# AWS: Hot to configure AWS credentials for multiple accounts in Mac OS terminal

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-cli

I found way to configure AWS credentials by

```
aws configure
```

command. But this is not very comfortable for me since I'm using multiple AWS accounts. Is there any way to make it easy to configure AWS credentials and switch between them?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can configure **multiple profiles**.

The easiest way is to use:

```
aws configure --profile <name>
```

You can then use it with:

```
aws s3 ls --profile <name>
```

If `--profile` is not specified, it will use the `default` profile.

All configuration information is stored in the `~/.aws/credentials` and `~/.aws/config` files.

See: [Named profiles - AWS Command Line Interface](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-profiles.html)